# creating pandas data frame in unittest

Tags: pandas, python-unittest

I am hitting an issue that I do not understand when trying to create a Pandas data frame in my unittest file. The error happens well before the functions within the class gets called.

Here is a simple code to reproduce:

```
import unittest
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

class simpleTest(unitest.TestCase):
    dates = pd.date_range('20160101', periods = 5)
    dataDf = pd.DataFrame({'date': dates,
            'count': np.array([3, 7, 4, 66, 9])})

    def doSomething(self):
        pass

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

The error I get is this:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "tsa_test.py", line 31, in <module>
    unittest.main()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 94, in __init__
    self.parseArgs(argv)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 149, in parseArgs
    self.createTests()
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/main.py", line 158, in createTests
    self.module)
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 130, in loadTestsFromNames
    suites = [self.loadTestsFromName(name, module) for name in names]
  File "/usr/local/Cellar/python/2.7.12/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/lib/python2.7/unittest/loader.py", line 100, in loadTestsFromName
    parent, obj = obj, getattr(obj, part)
AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute '-'
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your unittest code is problematic. You did right in subclassing `unittest.TestCase`, so this line is OK:

```
class simpleTest(unitest.TestCase):
```

However, this class should now have methods that look like:

```
     def test_foo(self):
         ...
```

(note that they should start with `test_`, and should take `self`). The omission of any such method is confusing unittest.

*Additionally*, you have static class members, which you probably meant to be used as class fixtures. That's [not how it's done in unittest](https://docs.python.org/2/library/unittest.html#setupclass-and-teardownclass). Your class should look like this:

```
class simpleTest(unitest.TestCase):
    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.dates = pd.date_range('20160101', periods = 5)
        cls.dataDf = pd.DataFrame({'date': cls.dates,
            'count': np.array([3, 7, 4, 66, 9])})

    def test_foo(self):
        # Note that here you access things like so:
        self.dataDF
        # even though you defined it as a class instance - that's how unittest works
```